# How to show two weeks by Day in same GridView?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot-table, common-table-expression

I am using this query to get the total of two week pay period per Employees.

```
select FullName
,[Sunday] = SUM([Sunday])
,[Monday] = SUM([Monday])
,[Tuesday] = SUM([Tuesday])
,[Wednesday] = SUM([Wednesday])
,[Thursday] = SUM([Thursday])
,[Friday] = SUM([Friday])
,[Saturday] = SUM([Saturday])
, Total=SUM(ISNULL([Sunday],0)+ISNULL([Monday],0)+ISNULL([Tuesday],0)+ISNULL([Wednesday],0)+ISNULL([Thursday],0)+ISNULL([Friday],0)+ISNULL([Saturday],0))
   from  
    (Select UserId_Fk,ISNULL(CAST(CountHours as decimal(18,2)),0)as CountHours,[Day],CheckIn 
    from CheckInCheckOut)
    as convertedtable
    inner join Users
    on convertedtable.UserId_Fk=Users.UserId
 PIVOT
(
 SUM(CountHours) 
 FOR Day
 IN([Sunday],[Monday],[Tuesday],[Wednesday],[Thursday],[Friday],[Saturday])
)
as PivotTable where CheckIn between @startdate and @enddate 
GROUP BY FullName
end
```

The output is like this:

[image]

How to update my query to show it as :

```
 Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Tursday Friday Saturday **Total**
```

Data in Database are:

[image]

**EDIT**
I have a table called Paperiod with list of all payperiods in current year:

First row of table is :

```
    Monday  21 Apr 2014 - 4 May 2014    

 ![enter image description here][3]
```

Example would be appreciated.

Comment: Which Sunday is the first Sunday?  Is one pay period 2014-05-04 through 2014-05-17, or is it 2014-05-11 through 2014-05-24?

Comment: I curious how you populate the Day column.  For example, all the dates in the first row refer to 2014-05-15, which is Thursday, but the Day column has Wednesday.  Is your query to be based on the contents of the Day column?  Or is it based on one of the date fields?

Comment: @DavidDubois Please see the update. I am bringing data accoring to day.

Comment: You can't have the same alias twice, you'll have to address that on the presentation layer

Answer (score 0):

Start with a query that computes the number of days from the start of the pay period to the day the employee worked.

```
select *, 
  DateDiff(day, @start_date, Day_Worked) as Day_Of_Period 
  from WorkHours
```

In this example, the new field, Day_Of_Period, will be number from 0 through 13.

Then generate the pivot based on that new field.

Comment: i tried you'r implementation but no success.. I know I can do it how you suggested... can you show me how to integrate your implementation in my query?

Answer (score 0):

May this help

```
SELECT 
    t1.FullName
    ,t1.[Monday]
    ,t1.[Tuesday]
    ,t1.[Wednesday]
    ,t1.[Thursday]
    ,t1.[Friday]
    ,t1.[Saturday]
    ,t1.[Sunday]
    ,t2.[Monday]
    ,t2.[Tuesday]
    ,t2.[Wednesday]
    ,t2.[Thursday]
    ,t2.[Friday]
    ,t2.[Saturday]
    ,t2.[Sunday]
    ,(t1.Total + t2.Total) AS Total
FROM 
    (
        SELECT FullName
            ,[Sunday] = SUM([Sunday])
            ,[Monday] = SUM([Monday])
            ,[Tuesday] = SUM([Tuesday])
            ,[Wednesday] = SUM([Wednesday])
            ,[Thursday] = SUM([Thursday])
            ,[Friday] = SUM([Friday])
            ,[Saturday] = SUM([Saturday])
            ,Total = SUM(ISNULL([Sunday], 0) + ISNULL([Monday], 0) + ISNULL([Tuesday], 0) + ISNULL([Wednesday], 0) + ISNULL([Thursday], 0) + ISNULL([Friday], 0) + ISNULL([Saturday], 0))
        FROM (
            SELECT UserId_Fk
                ,ISNULL(CAST(CountHours AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), 0) AS CountHours
                ,[Day]
                ,CheckIn
            FROM CheckInCheckOut
            ) AS convertedtable
        INNER JOIN Users ON convertedtable.UserId_Fk = Users.UserId
        PIVOT(SUM(CountHours) FOR Day IN (
                    [Sunday]
                    ,[Monday]
                    ,[Tuesday]
                    ,[Wednesday]
                    ,[Thursday]
                    ,[Friday]
                    ,[Saturday]
                    )) AS PivotTable
        WHERE CheckIn BETWEEN @startdate
                AND dateadd(day, 7, @startdate)
        GROUP BY FullName
    ) AS t1
INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT FullName
            ,[Sunday] = SUM([Sunday])
            ,[Monday] = SUM([Monday])
            ,[Tuesday] = SUM([Tuesday])
            ,[Wednesday] = SUM([Wednesday])
            ,[Thursday] = SUM([Thursday])
            ,[Friday] = SUM([Friday])
            ,[Saturday] = SUM([Saturday])
            ,Total = SUM(ISNULL([Sunday], 0) + ISNULL([Monday], 0) + ISNULL([Tuesday], 0) + ISNULL([Wednesday], 0) + ISNULL([Thursday], 0) + ISNULL([Friday], 0) + ISNULL([Saturday], 0))
        FROM (
            SELECT UserId_Fk
                ,ISNULL(CAST(CountHours AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), 0) AS CountHours
                ,[Day]
                ,CheckIn
            FROM CheckInCheckOut
            ) AS convertedtable
        INNER JOIN Users ON convertedtable.UserId_Fk = Users.UserId
        PIVOT(SUM(CountHours) FOR Day IN (
                    [Sunday]
                    ,[Monday]
                    ,[Tuesday]
                    ,[Wednesday]
                    ,[Thursday]
                    ,[Friday]
                    ,[Saturday]
                    )) AS PivotTable
        WHERE CheckIn BETWEEN dateadd(day, 7, @startdate)
                AND @enddate
        GROUP BY FullName
    ) AS t2 ON t1.FullName = t2.FullName
```